# How do I model these difficult parts of Apple Watch?

Tags: modeling

How do i model these 2 parts of an Apple Watch (Series 7)?
1:[image]

and
2:[image]

Comment: Hi :). What have you tried so far and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @JachymMichal I've tried Boolean in couple of different ways. Low poly, high poly too. But failing to reproduce clean controlled geometry . I'm unable to wrap my head around doing this in quad based geometry. :(